# mobile-ffmpeg-https (4.3.1) POD install failed

Tags: ios, flutter, ffmpeg, cocoapods

I am getting error on my pod install command , Error creating package is mobile-ffmpeg-https (4.3.1). Image attached for more details.

Actually i have not used this package anywhere in my project. I tried to use it and then removed it from project. But i am not getting why this is still showing up in pod install.

i tried deleting my podfile.lock and again running pod install but issue remains.

[image]

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Just try to install it with different wifi or mobile data, and you're done